# Numpy: find local co-ordinates within a submatrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Suppose we have a 4x4 matrix:

```
A = [[1,2]
     [3,4]]
```

We define another matrix:

```
C* = [[ 8, 4, 2, 4],
        6, 2, 6, 8],
        4, 2, 6, 4],
        6, 8, 2, 8]]]
```

and next we define C** as the matrix of minima of each 2x2 block:

```
C** = [[2, 2],
       [2, 2]]
```

We define a correspondence between C** and A:
1. locate the value of the cell in C** to the corresponding 2x2 block in C*.
2. The indices of this sub-block are indices of A, and the location of the minima in this sub-block is the corresponding location in A.

How can I efficiently find the corresponding indices in A?

Comment: you lost me at `C*`.  I wonder if it be easier to work with 2x2x2x2 arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj I've updated the question to clarify that C* is just a selection of numbers I've chosen for illustration purposes.

Comment: What are you asking then? To what value in A do values in C** correspond to? Or C*? Please edit to clarify the mapping.

Comment: I think I understand - you mixed (1,0) with (0,1).

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess, but maybe it will help

You aren't as to what `A` and `B` are, but I'm guessing they are meant to indices.  Since `numpy` is 0 base, lets change to that:

```
In [2010]: B=np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
In [2011]: B
Out[2011]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
```

So here's your `C`, and you want to work with 2x2 submatrices

```
In [2012]: C
Out[2012]: 
array([[8, 4, 2, 4],
       [6, 2, 6, 8],
       [4, 2, 6, 4],
       [6, 8, 2, 8]])
```

Reshape produces 4 2x2 arrays, but the grouping is wrong

```
In [2013]: C.reshape(2,2,2,2)
Out[2013]: 
array([[[[8, 4],
         [2, 4]],

        [[6, 2],
         [6, 8]]],


       [[[4, 2],
         [6, 4]],

        [[6, 8],
         [2, 8]]]])
```

But a transpose of 2 axes, gives the correct subarrays

```
In [2014]: C1=C.reshape(2,2,2,2).transpose(0,2,1,3)
In [2015]: C1
Out[2015]: 
array([[[[8, 4],
         [6, 2]],

        [[2, 4],
         [6, 8]]],


       [[[4, 2],
         [6, 8]],

        [[6, 4],
         [2, 8]]]])
```

simplify things by reshaping to 4x4; so each row is your subarray

```
In [2016]: C2=C1.reshape(4,4)
In [2017]: C2
Out[2017]: 
array([[8, 4, 6, 2],
       [2, 4, 6, 8],
       [4, 2, 6, 8],
       [6, 4, 2, 8]])
```

Now we can look for the minima on each row:

```
In [2018]: np.argmin(C2,axis=1)
Out[2018]: array([3, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
```

So the minima are:

```
In [2020]: C2[[0,1,2,3],[3,0,1,2]]
Out[2020]: array([2, 2, 2, 2])
```

`[0,1,2,3]` looks like a flattened `B`; and `[3,0,1,2]` looks like reordered `A`.

====================

In your original question you had A* and B* which can be constructed with tile and kron.  Applying the same reshaping:

```
In [2029]: B
Out[2029]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
In [2030]: np.kron(B,np.ones((2,2),int))     # your B*
Out[2030]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 3, 3]])
In [2031]: np.kron(B,np.ones((2,2),int)).reshape(2,2,2,2).transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(4,4)
Out[2031]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3]])

In [2032]: np.tile(B,(2,2)).reshape(2,2,2,2).transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(4,4)
Out[2032]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

So your B* and A* map on to the rows and columns of my transposed array.

=====================

The C2 argmin can be expressed as the coordinates in a 2x2 array with `unravel_index`:

```
In [2085]: idx=np.argmin(C2,axis=1)
In [2086]: idx
Out[2086]: array([3, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
In [2094]: idx1=np.unravel_index(idx,(2,2))
In [2095]: idx1
Out[2095]: (array([1, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int32), array([1, 0, 1, 0], dtype=int32))
In [2096]: np.transpose(idx1)
Out[2096]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Applying that 'local' index to the C1 array

```
In [2097]: C1.reshape(4,2,2)[np.arange(4), idx1[0], idx1[1]]
Out[2097]: array([2, 2, 2, 2])
```

or without the reshape

```
In [2100]: idx2=np.unravel_index(np.arange(4),(2,2))
In [2101]: C1[idx2[0],idx2[1], idx1[0], idx1[1]]
Out[2101]: array([2, 2, 2, 2])
```

Comment: I am confused by the second part. Additionally what does "[0,1,2,3] looks like a flattened B; and [3,0,1,2] looks like reordered A.", mean? are those the co-ordinates in A? They can't be, because they are not the local co-ordinates, they are co-ordinates based on C2, not on the submatrices.

Comment: I want the co-ordinates of the minima from each submatrix in C2. This means the co-ordinates would be one of (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1) for each minima.

Comment: I added the use of `np.unravel_index` to translate those 4x4 indices to 2x2x2x2 ones.